# Running task once in a slurm script with job array

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, slurm

I am running a couple of jobs in parallel using the following slurm script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name="example" 
#SBATCH --account="st-me-1"
#SBATCH --array=0-9
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=8
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=32000mb

# Change directory into the job dir
cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR

# Load conda environment
source ~/.bashrc

# Activate conda environment
conda activate env

# run the script
python3 script.py ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}


# Deactivate environment
conda deactivate
```

the python script creates some data and saves it to some file using the array task id.

Usually, after the calculation is done I manually run another python script that uses all the generated data and then collects them in a single file.

I only want to run that script once, and I also only want to run it after all the jobs from the array are completed. If I just added

```
python3 postprocessing_script.py
```

at the end of my slurm script would it result in the desired behaviour or will it run e.g. 10 times because the slurm script just keeps iterating over the jobs in the array?

What if I want to run something in parallel, do some post processing and then run something in parallel again? Does slurm know that it should only run something in parallel when using the array task id like so:

```
# run the first script in parallel
python3 script.py ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}

# do some post processing with the data
python3 postprocessing_script.py

# run another job in parallel
python3 second_script.py ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}

# Deactivate environment
conda deactivate
```

I guess I could also use some nested scripts that submit two or three different slurm scripts. Not sure what the best practice here is.